# Argument missing

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

Using: Django/Python

I'm trying to delete files...

it's showing this error:

> TypeError at /deletar_arquivo/18/  DeletarArquivoAnamnese() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'pk' and 'id_anamnese'.

template:

```
{% if arquivos_anamnese %}
        <section class="row width-100 d-flex ver-anamnese-info-queixa">
            <main class="col-xxl-12 width-100 d-flex flex-column">
                <div class="row mt-2 d-flex mt-width-100 ver-anamnese-info-queixa-perg">
                    {% for arquivo in arquivos_anamnese %}
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <a class="arquivos-ver-anamnese-box" href="{{ arquivo.arquivo.url }}" target="_blank">
                                {% if arquivo.arquivo|is_pdf %}
                                    <img class="arquivos-ver-anamnese-pdf" src="{% static 'icons/pdf.png' %}" alt="{{ arquivo.arquivo.name }}">  
                                {% else %}
                                    <img class="arquivos-ver-anamnese-img" src="{{ arquivo.arquivo.url }}" alt="{{ arquivo.arquivo.name }}">  
                                {% endif %}
                            </a>
                            <form method="post" action="{% url 'deletar_arquivo' arquivo_id=arquivo.id %}">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <button type="submit" class="delete-arquivo-ver-anamnese"><i class="fi fi-sr-cross-circle"></i></button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}

                </div>
                <div class="space-px"></div>
                <div class="space-px"></div>
            </main>{# col #}
        </section>
        {% endif %}
```

views:

```
def VerAnamnese(request, pk, id_anamnese):
    cliente_anamnese = get_object_or_404(Cad_Clientes, pk=pk)
    form_anamnese = get_object_or_404(Anamnese, id_anamnese=id_anamnese, id_paciente=cliente_anamnese)

    if form_anamnese.exame_sin_vitais_altura and form_anamnese.exame_sin_vitais_peso:
        imc = calcular_imc(peso=form_anamnese.exame_sin_vitais_peso, altura=form_anamnese.exame_sin_vitais_altura)
    else:
        imc = "" # define um valor nulo para o imc
        
    
    if form_anamnese.exame_sin_vitais_altura:
        alt = cm_m(form_anamnese.exame_sin_vitais_altura)
        print(alt)
    else:
        alt = ""
    
    # Recupere os objetos ArquivosAnamnese associados à instância de form_anamnese
    arquivos_anamnese = ArquivosAnamnese.objects.filter(Anamnese_arquivo=form_anamnese)

    return render(request, "base/base_ver_anamnese.html", {'cliente': cliente_anamnese, 'form': form_anamnese, 'imc': imc, 'altura': alt, 'arquivos_anamnese': arquivos_anamnese, 'id_anamnese': id_anamnese})


def DeletarArquivoAnamnese(request, arquivo_id, pk, id_anamnese):
    cliente_anamnese = get_object_or_404(Cad_Clientes, pk=pk)
    form_anamnese = get_object_or_404(Anamnese, id_anamnese=id_anamnese, id_paciente=cliente_anamnese)

    arquivos_anamnese = ArquivosAnamnese.objects.filter(Anamnese_arquivo=form_anamnese)

    arquivos = get_object_or_404(ArquivosAnamnese, arquivo_id=arquivo_id)
    arquivos.delete()
    return redirect(reverse('ver_anamnese', kwargs={'cliente': cliente_anamnese, 'form': form_anamnese, 'arquivos_anamnese': arquivos_anamnese, 'id_anamnese': id_anamnese}))
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', Plataforma, name="plataforma" ),
    path('cadastro/', Cadastro_Clientes, name="cadastro"),
    path('listagem_clientes/', Listagem_Clientes, name="listagem_clientes"),
    path('cliente/<int:pk>/', PerfilCliente, name="cliente"),
    path('cliente/<int:pk>/editar/', EditarCliente, name='editar_cliente'),
    path('cliente/<int:pk>/excluir/', ExcluirCliente, name='excluir_cliente'),
    path('cliente/<int:pk>/anamnese/', AnamneseForm, name="anamnese"),
    path('cliente/<int:pk>/anamnese/<int:id_anamnese>/', VerAnamnese, name="ver_anamnese"),
    path('cliente/<int:pk>/anamnese/<int:id_anamnese>/editar/', EditarAnamnese, name="editar_anamnese"),
    path('cliente/<int:pk>/anamnese/<int:id_anamnese>/excluir/', ExcluirAnamnese, name="excluir_anamnese"),    
    path('deletar_arquivo/<int:arquivo_id>/', DeletarArquivoAnamnese, name='deletar_arquivo'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

# Adicione esta linha para servir os arquivos de mídia durante o desenvolvimento
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Models:

```
class ArquivosAnamnese(models.Model):
    arquivo = models.FileField('Arquivos', upload_to='imagens/', null=True, blank=True)
    Anamnese_arquivo = models.ForeignKey(Anamnese, related_name='anamneses', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Outros campos que você desejar para descrever o arquivo, como nome, data, etc.
```

Forms:

```
class FormAnamnese(forms.ModelForm):

    id_paciente = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Cad_Clientes.objects.all())
    data_anamnese = forms.DateField(required=True, widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker-anamnese', 'type': 'date'}),input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d', '%d-%m-%Y'])
    arquivos = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
   * .....others forms...*
```

Could you find the errors?

I tried to change and include the missing arguments, but not successfully, I tried to include similar code from Ver_anamnese view.

Comment: Your `path('deletar_arquivo/<int:arquivo_id>/` has no `pk` and, `id_anamnese` path parameters.

Comment: your view function `def DeletarArquivoAnamnese(request, arquivo_id, pk, id_anamnese):` takes four arguments. The first `request` is automatically passed by Django when routing requests to the view, but the three others need to be supplied. But everywhere else you are only passing a single argument, e.g. the url path `'deletar_arquivo/<int:arquivo_id>/'` and in the template `{% url 'deletar_arquivo' arquivo_id=arquivo.id %}`